# CSS Side-by-side Divs

Tags: html, css

In the following example i'm trying to get the divs "left" and "right" to appear side-by-side. Obviously my understanding is flawed but what mistake have I made, because (in Chrome at least) they do not appear side-by-side.

Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: #ffffff;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #container {
      margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
      padding: 0;
      background: #eeeeee;
      text-align: left;
      width: 49.5em;
    }
    
    #title {
      margin: 2em;
      padding: 0;
      background: dddddd;
      width: 49.5em;
    }
    
    #graphics {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 200px;
      background: #cccccc;
      width: 49.5em;
    }
    
    #navigation {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: #bbbbbb;
      height: 3em;
      width: 49.5em;
    }
    
    #wrapper {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: #aaaaaa;
      width: 49.5em;
    }
    
    #left,
    #right {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      float: left;
      background: #999999;
      width: 41em;
    }
    
    #right {
      margin: 1.5em 0 0 0.5em;
      padding: 0;
      float: right;
      background: #888888;
      width: 8em;
    }
    
    .clear {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 0;
      font-size: 1px;
      line-height: 0;
      clear: both;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="title">Title</div>
    <div id="graphics">Graphics</div>
    <div id="menu">Menu Item</div>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="left">
        Left
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        Right
      </div>
      <div class="clear">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that you specified a 1.5em margin-top on `#right`. Take that out and it should work. Here's a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A5q8C/).

Answer (score 0):

remove margin from #right

```
    #right {
   /* margin: 1.5em 0 0 0.5em;*/
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    background: #888;
    width: 8em;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x5qaf/1/

Answer (score 0):

This fixes it for me:

```
#left {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    background: #999999;
    width: 41em;
}

#right {
    /* margin settings moved the box*/
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    background: #888888;
    width: 8em;
}
```